# PureComponent vs Component

Tags: reactjs

I am looking to understand the difference between **PureComponent vs Component in React**

I am relatively new to React and the video tutorial I am following gave a very brief Introduction about the differences.

Can anyone suggest articles to have a deeper understanding of this topic and also tell how does both differentiate in **shouldComponentUpdate**?

Comment: Did you try reading the docs? What part of the distinction is unclear?

Comment: Please do not add tags to the title; see https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging for details.

Comment: So, you answer on your question from another account. The same as with another questions from your account. A don't think this is the place where you can do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The major difference between the both comes down to `shouldComponentUpdate`

By default, When we extend a class component, it sets `shouldComponentUpdate` return value to `True` which means it will render everything, every time state changes (or props).

This causes **unnecessary render**, One way to overcome this problem is to use condition to check when your component needs to render in components.

For example like this (this is a shallow comparison, continue reading even if you don't know what s a shallow comparison)

```
shouldComponentUpdate (nextProps, nextState) {

    console.log("[Update App.js] Inside should Component Update")
    console.log(nextProps)
    console.log(nextState)
    //this should return True or False -> True Rendering updating continues, False -> Updating and rendering stops
    return nextState.person !== this.state.person ||
    nextState.showPerson !== this.state.showPerson
}
```

`PureComponent` by default will call shouldComponentUpdate and run a shallow comparison of props and state determining whether or not render should be invoked.

But `PureComponent` will only do a **very shallow check**,  You can't expect react to do Deep Nested check for objects and array you hence we say it to be shallow check.

*Note: To understand in sort of a simpler terms,  shallow quality check means that JS only checks that the value’s object ids (as in, the memory address for where JS stores the information for that particular object) are the same, not that their content is the same. On the other Deep quality check would be looping through every element to see if they are equal or not*

You can further read more about this here: https://reactjs.org/docs/shallow-compare.html